# Variable not in scope error in function using guards

Tags: haskell

I am trying to print a linked list in Haskell using the following code:

```
data List = Node {value:: Double, next:: List}
          |   Empty

printList :: List -> String
printList x | x == (Node v n) = show v ++ " " ++ printList n
            | otherwise = show '_'
```

And getting the compilation error:

```
:load scratch.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( scratch.hs, interpreted )

scratch.hs:5:26: error: Variable not in scope: v :: Double

scratch.hs:5:28: error: Variable not in scope: n :: List

scratch.hs:5:38: error: Variable not in scope: v

scratch.hs:5:53: error: Variable not in scope: n :: List
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

While I'm able to do the same using pattern matching without guards.

```
printList (Node v n) = show v ++ " " ++ printList n
printList Empty = ""
```

What's wrong with the first code?

Comment: In `printList (Node v n)`, `v` and `n` are arguments, but in `x == (Node v n)` they are two undefined variables.

Comment: @ForceBru So is there a way to distinguish which Data constructor x is using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not do *pattern matching* by using an equality check: it is possible that two different patterns are considered equal.

So what you can do is *define a pattern* in the head of one of the clauses of your function. For instance:

```
printList :: List -> String
printList (Node v n) = show v ++ " " ++ printList n
printList _ = show '_'
```

So now Haskell will, for a given `List` check if it matches with the `Node v n` pattern, and if so unpack the element and assign the head to `v` and the tail to `n`.

We can however still improve the code. Usually you better do not use wildcard patterns, but use all possible patterns. Since if you later want to alter the definition of `List`, the compiler can give you a warning that you forgot a pattern:

```
printList :: List -> String
printList (Node v n) = show v ++ " " ++ printList n
printList Empty = show '_'
```

Another thing we can improve is using `"_"` over `show '_'`. Since **`show '_'` will add quotes to the content**. For instance:

```
printList :: List -> String
printList (Node v n) = show v ++ " " ++ printList n
printList Empty = "_"
```

Finally we can also use a "cons" construction over appending with a singleton list:

```
printList :: List -> String
printList (Node v n) = show v ++ ' ' : printList n
printList Empty = "_"
```

Comment: But a piece of code that I wrote earlier has a function parameter `x` being compared against data constructors line `Meter`. Here's the code:  `data MetricUnit = Meter | Litre | Kilogram 
                deriving (Show, Eq)`                                                                                      `returnMetricSymbol x | x == Meter = "m"
                   | x == Litre = "L"
                   | x == Kilogram = "kg"`

Comment: @SafwanAhmad: that's because (1) you added `derving Eq`, and (2) here you only check for equality, you do not need to *unpack* the constructor, there are no parameters in your code that you are interested in.

Comment: Ok so my understanding is that using a Data constructor inside the guard statement is essentially creating new variables whereas if I use the same Data constructor as a function parameter, it is pattern matched. This means my code in the comment above is working by sheer chance because `Meter` is creating a new variable that  gets compared to `x` and the comparison is possible because I have derived `Eq`. Right?

Comment: More or less. By `deriving Eq`, you have defined implicitly a function `(==) :: MetricUnit -> MetricUnit -> Bool`. But for Haskell `==` is *just another function*. So for Haskell the `x == Meter` is no more special than `otherFunction x Meter`. It simply evaluates this and that returns `True`.